# Let me know once/when/after you got/get/bought/buy the laptop

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> Let me know once/when/after you got/get/bought/buy the laptop.

Which choice of words should I use, and what are the differences?

I am always confused about the tenses, and don't know which kind of tenses to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

"Let me know when you get/buy it" literally means 'at the time you buy it', though it needn't be interpreted literally.

"Let me know once/when you *have* got/*have* bought it" means 'when it is yours'.

"After you have bought it" could be used, but I find *once* or *when* more natural if the speaker is waiting to hear that the laptop has been bought.